# Unable to start Bank Heist

Tags: thief

I am  trying to start the Bank Heist mission in Thief. I go to the gate where you start the mission. I enter it and it loads. When it's done loading, I am back at the same gate as if the mission was never started. Is this a known glitch?

Comment: Is this the PC version? And just on the safe side, this is not a pirated copy?

Comment: Its the PC version, not pirated

Comment: Did you pre-order? That mission is currently a pre-order only DLC; since it shows up and tries to load I am assuming you did, but just to rule that out.

Comment: Yes I pre-ordered

Comment: I have this problem as well
Really hoping for a fix

Comment: Yeah f***ing annoying

Comment: I just bought this DLC on Steam. Where do I get the mission?